# Solr 5+ on Azure

Tags: java, azure, solr

How can we host Solr 5+ as a Java app on Azure? I am following this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-get-started/ to create a Java app in Azure.

However, Since Solr 5, Java Servlet (Tomcat) is inbuilt into the Solr install files, and it is an executable file!

Any idea, how to get it working on Windows Azure infrastructure that scales well when needed.

Comment: Your link points to app services, which is not an environment where you can install software such as Tomcat. You'll need to go with a VM. And how you go about that is up to you, regarding OS/distro, installation, etc.

Comment: Solr 5 does NOT bundle Tomcat. It does however bundle Jetty, but the previous practice of building a war file and deploying it in a servlet environment is no longer supported (it's possible, just not supported). The future will also move further away from the servlet model to be able to support wider and more distributed use cases.

Comment: So what is the best way to host Solr 5 + on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

There's an MS OpenTech project that runs Solr on Azure inside a Worker Role. It's been created for Solr 4.x but you should be able to modify it to work with the latest version.

https://github.com/MSOpenTech/Windows-Azure-Solr

If you want something that's easier to set up, you can get a pre-configured Linux image that includes Solr from VM Depot. This can be deployed easily to Azure:

https://vmdepot.msopentech.com/List/Index?sort=&search=solr

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can create an template Ubuntu VM contains Solr to install Solr 4.0.0/4.8.1/4.9.0 on the Azure new portal, as the follow picture.

[image]

If you have to install Solr 5+, I suggest you can create the Azure VM and follow the solr offical getstart document to do it.

On Azure, there is a cloud search-as-a-service solution called `Azure Search` that allows you to easily add a robust search experience to the application using a simple REST API or .NET SDK without managing search infrastructure and becoming an expert in search.

I recommend you can try to use the Azure Search to realize your needs. Please move to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-what-is-azure-search/ to know it.